# htaccess basic auth and Origin is not allowed

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, basic-authentication

I try with jquery to load an xml file. This xml is under a path with htaccess

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers *


AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/domains/subdomain.domain.com/.passwd
Require valid-user
```

If I request the file from the subdomain, it's ok, but if i request the same file from domain.com, I have this error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/path/file.xml?no=1381827329. Origin http://www.domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

If i remove the Basic Auth from htaccess, i have no problem.

I want to show the modal popup login, but i receive error.status 0.

Thanks bye!